# Create multi-word alias in bash?

Tags: git, bash

I want to create an alias in bash, such that

```
git diff somefile
```

becomes

```
git diff --color somefile
```

But I don't want to define my own custom alias like

```
alias gitd = "git diff --color"
```

because if I get used to these custom alias, then I loose the ability to work on machines which don't have these mappings.

**Edit**: It seems bash doesn't allow multi-word alias. Is there any other alternative solution to this apart from creating the alias?

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better answer (for this specific case).

From `git-config` man page:

```
   color.diff
       When set to always, always use colors in patch. When false (or
       never), never. When set to true or auto, use colors only when the
       output is to the terminal. Defaults to false.
```

No function or alias needed. But the function wrapper approach is general for any command; stick that card up your sleeve.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing this out. I like both your answers. But this one is very specific to my usecase. So selecting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32):

To create a smarter alias for a command, you have to write a wrapper function which has the same name as that command, and which analyzes the arguments, transforms them, and then calls the real command with the transformed arguments.

For instance your `git` function can recognize that `diff` is being invoked, and insert the `--color` argument there.

Code:

```
# in your ~/.bash_profile

git()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "diff" ] ; then
     shift
     command git diff --color "$@"
  else
     command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

If you want to support any options before `diff` and still have it add `--color`, you have to make this parsing smarter, obviously.

Comment: You might want to use `command git` instead of hard-coding the path.

Comment: I knew there is a way to refer to the original external command, but for the life of me I couldn't remember. :)

Answer (score 6):

Git has its own way to specify aliases (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Git-Aliases). For example:

```
git config --global alias.d 'diff --color'
```

Then you can use `git d`.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid blanks around assignment sign in bash:

```
alias gitd="git diff --color"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Set the `color.diff` config option to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise doing it, particularly, but you can always make aliases with non-breaking spaces (officially called no-break space; U+00A0; of course, you'll probably have to type them with your compose key or something, and your users might not appreciate that).

Example (copy and paste):

```
alias git diff="git diff --color"
```

You might be able to come up with a way to autoreplace `git diff` with `git diff`, though, or something wild like that.